# link data from json with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello this the link to my old question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567791/get-more-data-from-json-with-javascript?
i have put some work in my code and i get some of the result that i need but I am still have some problems.

1- when i click in the link it plays the loop again and give me all books from all the categories .
2-the first Category Id is not showing in the links.
**here the code for my HTML**.

```
    <html>
<body>

<br/>
<div id="placeList">

</div>

<div id="Book">

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**this my JavaScript code** :
Updated

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var output = $('#placeList');
$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.example.com/book/showcat.php',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data, status){
var setid=[];
      $.each(data, function(i,item){

             var place = '<li class="new"><a  onclick="'+getcategery(item.caid)+'" href="#book'+item.caid+'">'+item.catname+
                '</a></li>';

               output.append(place);

            });

    }
});

function getcategery(cataid){
$(".new").click(function (){

$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.example.com/book/catid.php?caid='+cataid,
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data, status){

$.each(data, function(i,item){
var cate = '<li>'+ item.bookname +'</li>';
output.append(cate);
});


},

error: function(){
output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
}
});



});
}
});
```

**now it shows me the categories when the page loads and if you click in Category(1)   in the list it shows you the Category(2) and Category(3) books .it should only show you the Category that you click on it books .**

Comment: Why are you using an array `setid`? Why not passing `item.caid` to `getcategery()` method? BTW, you should rename your variables with more relevant name, e.g `getcategory()`

Comment: I use setid for testing propose and forget to remove it from Here .

Comment: Hello after some search i have figure to solve some of the problem